# ¿Cómo acomodar un video de AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift

Me gustaría acomodar mi vídeo en la parte superior de la pantalla ocupando todo su ancho y abajo poner una lista.

```
let videoURLWithPath = "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
let videoURL = NSURL(string: videoURLWithPath)
let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL!)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()
```

Se podría poner el reproductor en un View?

Answer (score 0):

Esta parte tendrias que sustituirla por la vista creada y su frame

```
playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
```